# How to tar single file into multiple directories?

Tags: linux, command-line

I just downloaded latest.tar.gz from Wordpress
I want to tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz into folder1 folder2 folder3 etc so each folder will have everything in it from the file.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
for i in 'folder1' 'folder2' 'folder3'; do
  ( cd "$i" && tar -zxvf - ) < latest.tar.gz
done
```